# How can I launch a Powerpoint presentation in the browser full-screen?

Tags: vba, browser, hyperlink, powerpoint

My default browser is set to Firefox, however I want to open a hyperlink in a powerpoint slide show in IE (full screen). 
I've used the following macro:

```
Sub hyperlink()
sCmd = """C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"" " _
& "http://www.google.com/"
Shell sCmd
End Sub
```

When I click on the hyperlink it opens the site in IE, but on the background. I still have to exit Powerpoint. Is there a possibilty to open the link instantly in full screen mode?

Answer (score 1):

Could try Internet Explorer's kiosk mode with the -k switch

However PowerPoint will still be open and to exit kiosk mode you need to use Alt-F4

This code should also bring IE to the foreground

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow% Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                                          (ByVal lpclassname As Any, _
                                           ByVal lpCaption As Any)

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                 ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
                                 ByVal X As Long, _
                                 ByVal y As Long, _
                                 ByVal cx As Long, _
                                 ByVal cy As Long, _
                                 ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Global Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Global Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Global Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2

Sub hyperlink()
sCmd = """C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"" -k " _
& "http://www.google.com/"
Shell sCmd
hwnd% = FindWindow%("Internet Explorer", 0&)
Call SetWindowPos(hwnd%, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or _
      SWP_NOSIZE)
End Sub
```

Tested on Win 10 x64, PowerPoint 2013 & IE11